# time series equation in R

Tags: r, time-series, equation

I have data that looks similar to the following example data and I'm looking for a way to fit an equation that i can use on other data with similar profiles but might be higher or lower.

```
structure(list(day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 
107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 
120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 
146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 
159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 
172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 
185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 
198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 
211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 
224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 
237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 
250, 251, 252, 253), Count = c(10, 50, 500, 425, 300, 400, 275, 
98, 115, 79, 87, 114, 69, 105, 81, 82, 117, 87, 123, 81, 119, 
97, 84, 124, 122, 53, 114, 95, 49, 95, 101, 114, 74, 120, 72, 
61, 79, 59, 96, 95, 105, 53, 110, 69, 69, 79, 106, 52, 50, 98, 
102, 107, 122, 108, 47, 68, 51, 114, 96, 102, 121, 113, 130, 
134, 143, 144, 141, 139, 140, 142, 141, 125, 134, 130, 137, 139, 
123, 138, 108, 133, 97, 122, 120, 110, 144, 121, 103, 127, 103, 
100, 139, 138, 103, 105, 114, 142, 128, 141, 141, 122, 110, 125, 
112, 98, 130, 116, 138, 120, 135, 143, 136, 145, 101, 120, 131, 
119, 131, 116, 114, 143, 126, 102, 116, 106, 133, 110, 102, 141, 
141, 132, 110, 95, 130, 133, 131, 128, 103, 111, 120, 140, 107, 
114, 95, 113, 116, 131, 145, 144, 121, 111, 100, 145, 96, 130, 
95, 119, 135, 127, 113, 105, 110, 102, 105, 116, 145, 115, 102, 
120, 143, 140, 141, 132, 143, 136, 108, 106, 127, 112, 122, 118, 
112, 96, 116, 141, 162, 168, 198, 156, 165, 180, 179, 166, 194, 
194, 162, 199, 156, 193, 200, 160, 160, 187, 150, 185, 161, 183, 
166, 167, 199, 159, 146, 195, 151, 161, 161, 162, 167, 193, 191, 
181, 148, 200, 182, 164, 147, 182, 165, 165, 159, 163, 188, 154, 
192, 157, 149, 163, 170, 151, 185, 168, 154, 164, 191, 169, 186, 
157, 182, 195, 150, 145, 152, 188, 176)), row.names = c(NA, -253L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The red line is an example of what an equation might look like. Very rough drawing.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you may be looking for is a generalized additive model (GAM), which is often used to model nonlinear data like time. Here I have saved your `dput` as `data` and fit it to a GAM below. First, we can load the mgcv package for the GAM fit.

```
#### Load Library ####
library(mgcv)
```

Then you fit the GAM. This can be a very complex topic, and I advise reading a lot on this, but essentially you fit the regression in a similar manner you are probably used to if you have done regression in R before. The only difference is what spline terms you add to the regression, or the nonlinear functions that approximate the relationship between x and y. Here I have just fit a cubic regression spline using the `s` function for the spline, "day" as the variable, and `bs = "cr"` for the cubic regression spline. I also use REML here, recommended by a lot of GAM experts, to automatically adjust the knots and smoothing parameters. This can be customized a lot, but for simplicity I leave it alone here.

```
#### Fit GAM ####
fit <- gam(
  Count ~ s(day, bs = "cr"),
  method = "REML",
  data=data
)
```

The results can be run here:

```
#### Summary ####
summary(fit)
```

As seen below. Here you see the intercept is listed like typical regression summaries. Now you have an additional "Approximate significance of smooth terms" section, which lists some useful metrics for your smoothing term. EDF is how curvilinear it is, and Ref.df & F are used for the significance test, seen to the far right. In this case, the smoothing term is significant. There are also many model metrics on the bottom that are worth observing:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
Count ~ s(day, bs = "cr")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  133.538      2.504   53.32   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(day) 8.037  8.751 17.93  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.382   Deviance explained = 40.2%
-REML = 1298.7  Scale est. = 1586.9    n = 253
```

Technically we can write an equation based off this knowledge, but the difference with GAMs is that each spline fit sets separate coefficients for each part of the nonlinear trend, so its not entirely useful for nonlinear data (some reasons [are given here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_write_out_a_complete_GAM_model_as_an_equation)). For example, if I want all of the coefficients for a linear equation, I can run `coef(fit)` and get this very long list:

```
(Intercept)    s(day).1    s(day).2    s(day).3    s(day).4    s(day).5 
 133.537549  -83.413590  -54.926693  -35.398280  -38.849985  -41.564495 
   s(day).6    s(day).7    s(day).8    s(day).9 
 -38.991790    9.101440    4.764924   24.764163
```

Plotting the data can be done with the below function and is a much better approximation of the regression fit:

```
#### Plot Fit ####
plot(fit)
```

Which shows the data fit with its spline and standard error, along with a rug showing the data points with lines on the x axis. This plotting can be customized a lot too, especially with the `gratia` package, but I leave it here as is. In any case, the interpretation from the plot is far more clear...counts initially decrease a ton, then rebound slightly, plateau for some time, then rebound again before plateauing again.

[image]

Hope that is helpful and I recommend reading a lot on this topic. I have included some links to some really useful primers on the subject below.

Citations

- [Simpson, 2018: GAMs article.](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fevo.2018.00149/full) This covers mostly fixed effect versions, which you are probably more likely to use.
- [Pedersen et al., 2019: GAMMs article.](https://peerj.com/articles/6876/) This covers some random effects parts too, which may be difficult to understand unless you know more about mixed models.

[This book](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781315370279/generalized-additive-models-simon-wood) is also a canonical reference to GAMs that is a lot more comprehensive, but I find it is a difficult read and not the best source for beginners.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such a detailed answer. I will definitely look into the citations as well. Appreciate the help!

Comment: No prob. Good luck. Noam Ross's free online course is also nice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i got it right,
are you looking for the code to make this kind of plot?
install tidyverse (a collection of packages) and then -
Add this piece of code:

```
# your code first and then use the pipe operator '%>%':
%>% 
ggplot(aes(x = day, y = Count))+geom_line()
```

[image: plot created by your data]

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I am looking for  a way to generalize the data into an equation of sorts so i can vary the inputs based on different sales forecasts, with the same trend line similar to the plot.

Comment: https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/nonlinear-regression-in-r/#:~:text=R%20Non%2Dlinear%20regression%20is%20a%20regression%20analysis%20method%20to,and%20dependencies%20of%20the%20data.    Please check this source, you might find useful information regarding non-linear modeling.

Comment: Excellent resource, thanks!